# libopencv2.3-dev conflict Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit

Tags: ros, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just wondering when could the problem be fixed?

I'm running a 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10, and the installation of ros-electric-desktop-full always ends up with the following error.

xxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-desktop-full : Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.7-s1320939105~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.3-s1320939324~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1320939218~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

Installation of ros-electric-vision-opencv ends up with the following

xxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-vision-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-vision-opencv : Depends: libopencv2.3-dev (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-7~oneiric) but 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~oneiric is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

xxx@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11943/libopencv2.3-dev-conflict-ubuntu-11.10-32-bit/) by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The same question is asked here
http://answers.ros.org/question/2887/libopencv23-dev-conflict

we are waiting for an update for the opencv package in 11.10 i386.

---

Originally posted by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) with karma: 126 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2